# Deploying selenium on heroku (Chrome binary not detected)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to deploy selenium script using flask on heroku.

I added the following buildpacks

1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

And I also created config variables as:

1. `CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "/my-app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver"`
2. `GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM = "/my-app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome"`

And below is the Python snippet for referring to chromedriver:

```
chrome_bin = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', None)
opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.binary_location = chrome_bin
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", chrome_options=opts)
```

But when i open my app following error occurred:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /tmp/build_4cef63dfa1c952837ceb30f2e894524a/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`

PLEASE HELP!!!!

Comment: You should not use selenium on heroku, it is not meant for it. Get a online service like browserstack, saucelabs or something else and then use remote webdriver

Answer (score 1):

GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM is set wrongly in the config.
Use the below config instead.

opts.binary_location = "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"

That worked for me.